# jQuery modifying element after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a small problem with my jQuery code:

```
function afterVoting(id, votes, direction) {
    $('.votebtn').each(function(i,o) {
        if($(this).data('fbid') == id) {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.grlvotes').text(votes); // THIS DOESN'T UPDATE
            $(this).shake(direction);
        }
    });
}

$(document).on('click', '.votebtn', function(e) {
    var voted = $(this).data('fbid');
    $.get('....', function(data) {
        $('.votesself').text(data.idata.votes_self); // this works because its not modified element
        afterVoting(voted, data.result.votes, data.result.vote ? {direction:'top'} : {direction:'left'});
    });
});
```

The shake method is executed OK **but the line before is not**. Button is shaking, but the 'grlvotes' is not updated.
Here is the NEXT PAGE code and appending content to the page from call:

```
$('.nextpage').click(function() {
    if(page + 1 <= maxpage) {
        $('#loading').show();
        page++;
        $.get('.....', function(data) {
            showGirls(data);
            maxpage = data.idata.maxpage;
            $('.pagenum').text(page);
        });
    }
});

function showGirls(data) {
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('.grl').remove();
    $(data.result).each(function(i,o) {
        var girl = 'just long HTML code with data from AJAX call';
        $('.grlwrapper').append(girl);
    });
    forceImageLoading();
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="grl">
    <div class="data"> <b>VOTES</b>  <span class="grlvotes">0</span>

    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="votebtn" data-fbid=""><b>VOTE</b> 
            <img src="img/like.png" alt="like" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've got a code that appends the 'grl' to the main wrapper (from AJAX call). First time you load the page, 'grls' are loaded by PHP and everything works fine. But when you click 'Next Page' and 'grls' are loaded by AJAX call, it's getting problematic.

Any ideas, why it is not updating ?

Comment: Please post your html in the question

Comment: It should be in the question as well, in case the js fiddle is removed in the future and also so the question can be answered without the jsfiddle

Comment: Please update your post to include the `$.get()` call as well. It sounds like you are modifying the DOM as a result of that call and it will be easier to diagnose the issue if the code that updates the DOM can be seen.

Comment: I added a lot more code so you can see mostly everything

Comment: The  HTML you posted has an extra </div> tag?

Comment: Check your console, does `$(this).parent().parent().find('.grlvotes')` exist? How about do something more simple try changing it to just `$('.grlvotes').text(...)` and see if that works (for testing purposes). Also it looks like you missing a `<div>`.

Comment: Console says it exists. And no <div> or </div> is missing. It just looks like that.

Comment: is this data attribute on the element blank really? <div class="votebtn" data-fbid="">

Comment: It actually exists in the real code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery<=1.7 then use

```
$(element).live("click",function(){
});
```

instead of

```
$(element).click(function(){
});
```

for jquery appended elements and if you are using jquery>1.7 then use

```
$(element).on("click",function(){
});
```

Comment: That's not really needed. I am using it with the .votebtn but nextpage doesn't need it (it's not modified by ajax)